# Use JSONPATH to get configmap value

Tags: kubernetes, jsonpath

How can I retrieve a configmap value using jsonpath?

I'm trying to retrieve the value of haproxy.cfg from my configmap, but I can't get it just right:

```
kubectl get cm -l app=haproxy -o jsonpath="{['items'][0]['data']['haproxy.cfg']}"
```

The above returns no results.  But I can definitely get the configmap if I leave off the haproxy.cfg:

```
kubectl get cm -l app=haproxy -o jsonpath="{['items'][0]['data']}"
```

Yields:

```
map[haproxy.cfg:
global
  user root
  group root
  maxconn 256
...
]
```

I can use jq:

```
kubectl get cm -l app=haproxy -o json | jq -r '.items[0].data["haproxy.cfg"]'
```

which yields exactly what I want:

```
global
  user root
  group root
  maxconn 256
```

If you need help creating your ConfigMap, here's the manifest for the one I am using:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
    haproxy.cfg: "\nglobal\n  user root\n  group root\n  maxconn 256\n\n"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
    annotations:
      meta.helm.sh/release-name: haproxy
      meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: haproxy
    labels:
      app: haproxy
      app-version: 2.4.0
      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
      heritage: Helm
      release: haproxy
      version: 0.0.3
    name: haproxy
```

Comment: try `{['items'][0]['data'][0]}` or can you provide manifest file to create the `cm` to play around ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape the `.` inside single quotes

```
kubectl get cm -l app=haproxy -o jsonpath="{.items[0].data['haproxy\.cfg']}"
```

* This didn't work a long time ago, pre 1.5. Then you needed to use `go-template` formatting.

Answer (score 1):

[I have created](https://www.bmc.com/blogs/kubernetes-configmap/) simple configmap.

```
kubectl get cm game-config-example -o json
```

returns:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "data": {
        "game.properties": "enemies=aliens\nlives=3\nenemies.cheat=true\nenemies.cheat.level=noGoodRotten\nsecret.code.passphrase=UUDDLRLRBABAS\nsecret.code.allowed=true\nsecret.code.lives=30",
        "ui.properties": "color.good=purple\ncolor.bad=yellow\nallow.textmode=true\nhow.nice.to.look=fairlyNice\n"
    },
    "kind": "ConfigMap",
    "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": "2021-06-16T10:08:28Z",
        "name": "game-config-example",
        "namespace": "default",
        "resourceVersion": "24666141",
        "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps/game-config-example",
        "uid": "3d6d2ba0-8f5a-43a7-953b-91a62dbcd248"
    }
}
```

I have tested solution with escaping `.` characters on versions 1.19 and 1.21. Both works fine.

```
kubectl get cm game-config-example -o jsonpath="{['data']['ui\.properties']}"
```

gives right output:

```
color.good=purple
color.bad=yellow
allow.textmode=true
how.nice.to.look=fairlyNice
```

Same result I can achive if I use:

- `go-template`:

```
kubectl get cm game-config-example -o 'go-template={{index .data "ui.properties" }}'
```

- `jq` command:

```
kubectl get cm game-config-example -o json | jq -r '.data."ui.properties"'
```

You can see also [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23386) -  JSONpath fails to return keys containing dots in a map.

Comment: I was able to get your approach to work when I selected the CM by name (and thus did not receive a list back from kube).  Here's what worked for me `kubectl get cm haproxy  -o 'go-template={{index .data "haproxy.cfg" }}'`

Comment: Selecting my cm by label, I was also able to get the gotemplate to wokr like this `kubectl get cm -l app=haproxy  -o 'go-template={{ range .items }}{{index .data "haproxy.cfg" }}{{ end }}'`  - thanks for the go-template suggestion.